# Flux Integral using Calculus

Tags: calculus

How do I do this question:

> Let $\mathbf F=3x\mathbf i+5y\mathbf j$ and let $\mathbf n$ be the outward unit normal vector to the positively oriented circle $x^2+y^2=4$. Compute the flux integral $\int_C\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf n\,\mathrm ds$.

Also how does $n$ affect how I write my integral?

I am really confused because there are so many formulas, theorems, and variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation of the Surface is given by $G(x,y) = x^2+y^2-4=0$. You obtain the unit normal vector by plugging this equation into the formula: $\vec{n} = \frac{grad G(x,y)}{|grad G(x,y)|}$. Then you can compute the scalar product $\vec{F} \vec{n}$.

Now you can Change to polar coordinates since you integrate over a circle with radius $2$. Set $x=2cos \phi,y=2sin \phi$ and the Surface element is given by $ds = 2 d \phi$.

Comment: This would be a double integral?

Comment: This will be a single integral because you integrate only over all possible angles $\phi$ of the circle. The radius (=2) of the circle remains constant on the "Surface" of the circle.

Comment: How did you find the surface element? Also doesn't the magnitude of the gradient get cancelled with ds?

Comment: $gradG = (2x,2y)^T,|gradG|= 2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. $\vec{F} \vec{n} = 3x* \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + 5y* \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{3x^2+5y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Now you can use polar coordinates with Surface element $ds = rd \phi$ (is the length of an infinitesimal circle arc).